# how to update window(table) a table in tksheet?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkintertable

> **Hello friends how can I update the window in tksheet. I have a database.Which connects to Postgresql and pulls out data. In addition,
> I can choose the date of the data, from which to which.After starting,
> I select the dates and click on the "Get data" button.The first time
> is displayed. After the first time, the data is not output to the
> interface.But it is displayed in the console. You can't select the
> date a second time and display it on the interface. I think that you
> need to update the window, if so, as soon as possible.**

```
       def sec_frame(self):
           global date_from1, date_from2
           sec_frame1 = Frame(self.master, background='#21acfc', )
           sec_frame1.pack()

           query_button = tk.Button(sec_frame1, text='Get data', width=200, command=self.get_datas)
           query_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=40)

           date_from1 = DateEntry(sec_frame1, background='#e03aca', font="Helvetica 14", locale='KY')
           date_from1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50)

           date_from2 = DateEntry(sec_frame1, background='#e03aca', font="Helvetica 14",locale='KY')
           date_from2.pack(side=LEFT)
     
    
        def get_datas(self):
            date1 = date_from.get_date()
            date2 = date_to.get_date()
            query_datas= f"select *from client_info where date_to='{date1}'::date and date_from='{date2}'::date"
            self.cursor.execute(query_datas)
            get_datas = self.cursor.fetchall()
            print(get_datas) #I actually get the data in the console
            try:
                get_datas[0]
            except IndexError:
                messagebox.showerror('some text', 'some text')
    
            lenn = len(get_datas)
            len1 = len(get_datas[0])
            bottom_frame = Frame(self.master, )
            table = Sheet(bottom_frame, page_up_down_select_row=True, column_width=120, startup_select=(0, 1, "rows"),
                          data=[[get_datas[r][c] for c in range(len1)] for r in range(lenn)],
                          height=1000,
                          width=1920
                          )
            table.enable_bindings(("single_select",
                                   "drag_select",
                                   "column_drag_and_drop",
                                   "row_drag_and_drop",
                                   "column_select",
                                   "row_select",
                                   "column_width_resize",
                                   "double_click_column_resize",
                                   "arrowkeys",
                                   "row_height_resize",
                                   "double_click_row_resize",
                                   "right_click_popup_menu",
                                   "rc_select",
                                   "rc_insert_column",
                                   "rc_delete_column",
                                   "rc_insert_row",
                                   "rc_delete_row",
                                   "hide_columns",
                                   "copy",
                                   ))
            bottom_frame.pack()
            table.pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: You created new big `table` (1920x1000) every time `get_datas()` is called and so the second table is *packed* outside the viewable area of the window.  You should either delete the previous table or update the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** thank you very much. You were right. I did this.  In the sec_frame function, I created the global variables table, bottom_frame. I called these global variables in the get_datas function and passed an empty value to the table table.set_sheet_data(data=[]). Every time I click the button first, I pass empty data to the table. Then the received request passed again table. set_sheet_data(data=[......]).And at the end of bottom_frame, table made a pack() **